# seo duplicate content issue

Tags: asp.net, web-config, seo

I have an asp.net site and when I checked it in an analyzer site it commented that my site having the issue of duplicate content...www.mysite.com and mysite.com are showing the same content...
 some sites suggested that adding something like the below link would solve the problem:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.mysite.com" />
```

but apparently it wouldn't...someone told me that I should fix it in web.config of the site however I couldn't find the solution...is there any suggestion about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can add global filter to remove duplicates based on different urls:

```
public class RemoveDuplicateContentAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var routes = RouteTable.Routes;
        var requestContext = filterContext.RequestContext;
        var routeData =requestContext.RouteData;
        var dataTokens = routeData.DataTokens;
        if (dataTokens["area"] == null)
            dataTokens.Add("area", "");
        var vpd = routes.GetVirtualPathForArea(requestContext, routeData.Values);
        if (vpd != null)
        {
            var virtualPath = vpd.VirtualPath.ToLower();
            var request = requestContext.HttpContext.Request;
            if (!string.Equals(virtualPath, request.Path))
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(virtualPath + request.Url.Query, true);
            }
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Then add this filter in your global.asax file:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new RemoveDuplicateContentAttribute());
}
```

Comment: thanks...shall I use the first part in an ordinary .cs file then use the other code in global.asax?

Comment: @sara.y exacly. First as a separate cs file than register it in global.asax.cs

Answer (score 1):

You should decide which domain you would like to use, and set permanent redirect(301) to it.

One of possible solutions, to use IIS Url Rewrite module(but you it it must be supported by your provider, or you will have to add it by yourself). Let's say you want to redirect from mysite.com to www.mysite.com:

```
   <rewrite>
     <rules>
       <rule name="You name here" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)"/>
        <conditions>             
         <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mysite.com$"/>
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://www.mysite.com/{R:1}"/>
       </rule>
     </rules>
   </rewrite>
```

If you can't use it, it's not hard write you own module wich will redirect all request to certain domain

Comment: thanks for answering...shall I put this code in <system.web> tag?

Comment: @sara.y yep, but make sure that module installed

Comment: it seems I don't have it by default...how should I install it on my server?

Comment: @sara.y easiest way to use `Web Platform Installer`